# Traverse an object or array to determine if elements fit within ranges

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object

I am building a decorator for arrays of items, the array of objects is meant to be slotted into a defined range of values if it fits there.

Currently, I am doing this using some conditionals to check for the range but the code does not feel clean enough to me.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how write this code in a more concise and expandable way?

Example of current setup...

```
thingsToSort.forEach(function(thing) {
    if (thing > 1 || thing < 3) {
        // set the item to 1
    }
    if (thing > 3 || thing < 5) {
        // set to 3
    }
})
```

Note: I am really looking for a better way to loop through this logic and determine if object falls in the range.

Comment: Any limitations? Can you use external libraries like lodash or underscores? Will you target ES5/ES6?

Answer (score 2):

One another implementation.

1. Created a function to represent the Range, `Range`
2. A function to identify the range and take appropriate action. `setcompareRange`

Notice the usage of the `some` method in the function `compareRange`. Since a number can be found in one range only, All the ranges are not evaluated and till the matched range traversal is done.

```js
function Range(min, max){
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
}

var rangeArray = [ new Range(1,3), new Range(3,5)];

function compareRange(c,i,arr){
    var result = rangeArray.some(x=> {
        return setcompareRange(c, x.min, x.max)
    });
}

function setcompareRange(thing, min, max){
    if (thing > min && thing < max) {
        // set the item to 1
        console.log("set thing = " + thing + " in range = " + min);
        return true;
    }
}

var thingsToSort = [2,4];
thingsToSort.forEach(compareRange);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first double-check your logic...

```
thingsToSort.forEach(function(thing) {
```

This conditional will set ANYTHING greater than 1 to 1, and ignore the second condition (`thing < 3`):

```
    if (thing > 1 || thing < 3) {
        // set the item to 1
    }
```

You should be using an `&&` operator to `AND` these two conditions:

```
    if (thing > 1 && thing < 3) {
        // set the item to 1
    }
```

The same thing goes for this conditional which will set ANYTHING greater than 3 to 3.

```
    if (thing > 3 || thing < 5) {  //should be &&
        // set to 3
    }
})
```

You are also not breaking the loop after meeting a conditional. This means that even though you have already determined that a thing meets the first condition, you are still checking to see if it meets the other conditions. This wastes resources. Use `else if` to prevent this:

```
    if (thing > 1 && thing < 3) {
        // set the item to 1
    }
    else if (thing > 3 && thing < 5) {
        // set to 3
    }
```

Other than that, it's already pretty clean. This is very similar to the classic [fizzbuzz](https://gist.github.com/jaysonrowe/1592432) problem, of which, there are many possible refactorings